# Base64Encoded bitmap - convert to bitmap manually

Tags: c#, bitmap, base64

I know I can use

```
string base64Encoded = ...; 
byte[] byteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(this.base64Encoded); // array size [31591]

var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
var bitmap = new Bitmap(memoryStream);
//byte[,] im = new byte[a.Width*a.Height,3]; 
// array size [891998, 3] - why this array is 90 times bigger?
```

but I want to do it manually.

What I really need is to know how from byteArray I can create 3dim pixel array [bitmap.width * bitmap.hight, 3 {Red,Green,Blue}]

Comment: You want to convert to bitmap manually (i.e. var bitmap = new Bitmap(memoryStream);) looking for only this code or do you want the conversion logic for Convert.FromBase64String function also .......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- size of `byteArray` is different from size of `bitmap` since `bitmap` is actually an uncompressed 24 bit image without a header, but `byteArray` is a compressed (RLE most likely) bitmap file.

2- you can use libbmp or another image processing library to load and manipulate pixels. These libraries are much better at handling that kind of stuff.

3- most bitmaps are compressed using RLE compression and bitmap is a very simple format. You can actually write a bitmap reader to read it to a byte array intead of Bitmap object.